# Replacing NA of numbered column in list of data frames

Tags: r, list, replace, na, purrr

I have a large list of dataframes of the following structure:

```
foo <- 1:5
lorem1968 <- c(6, NA, NA, 8, NA)
lorem1969 <- c(NA, 17, NA, 19, 20)
df1 <- data.frame(foo, lorem1968, lorem1969)

ipsum <- 11:15
lorem1970 <- c(22, NA, 24, NA, NA)
df2 <- data.frame(ipsum, lorem1969, lorem1970)

df.list <- list(df1, df2)

[[1]]
  foo lorem1968 lorem1969
1   1         6        NA
2   2        NA        17
3   3        NA        NA
4   4         8        19
5   5        NA        20

[[2]]
  ipsum lorem1969 lorem1970
1    11        NA        22
2    12        17        NA
3    13        NA        24
4    14        19        NA
5    15        20        NA
```

I would like now to iterate over all columns named loremxxxx and replace all NA's there with 0. Then, I would like to create a new column in each df which contains the average of all loremxxxx columns contained in that specific df.

The problem is that these are overlapping panels in the original data, so any df1 contains lorem1968, lorem1969, lorem1970. df2 contains lorem1969, 1970, 1971. And so on.

I tried to select the columns like this:

```
lorem.cols <- purrr::map(panels.list, function(x)
  select(x, starts_with("lorem"))
  )
```

and also:

```
lorem.cols <- purrr::map(df.list, function(data)
  data %>% select(data, starts_with("lorem"))
)
```

but both threw an error of either not finding the function or of giving me "Selection:" and waiting for input. Just tried to copy from the help page of the `select()` function.

After I planned on replacing NAs like so:

```
df.list <- purrr::map(df.list, function(data)
  data %>% mutate(lorem.cols = replace(is.na(lorem.cols), 0))
  )
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Looks like a good answer below, but fyi, the problem with select is fixed here: ```lorem.cols <- purrr::map(df.list, function(x)
  dplyr::select(x, dplyr::starts_with("lorem"))
)```

Comment: ouh that's very good to know thanks! Only half way done with that project and good to know I can get my tidyverse functions on board that way :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `base R`.  Loop through the `list` with `lapply`, use `grep` to find the index of the column names that match 'lorem' followed by one or more digits, `replace` the `NA`s in those columns with 0, and `transform` the original dataset in the `list` to create a new column 'avg' by getting the `mean` of those 'lorem' columns

```
lapply(df.list, function(x) {
         i1 <- grep("^lorem\\d+$", names(x))
         x[i1] <- replace(x[i1], is.na(x[i1]), 0)
    transform(x, avg = rowMeans(x[i1], na.rm = TRUE))
   })
#[[1]]
#  foo lorem1968 lorem1969  avg
#1   1         6         0  3.0
#2   2         0        17  8.5
#3   3         0         0  0.0
#4   4         8        19 13.5
#5   5         0        20 10.0

#[[2]]
#  ipsum lorem1969 lorem1970  avg
#1    11         0        22 11.0
#2    12        17         0  8.5
#3    13         0        24 12.0
#4    14        19         0  9.5
#5    15        20         0 10.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm! Best answer since I cannot always guarantee that there are no other NAs in my data frame. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach that relies on `data.table` update-by-reference that holds true in `lapply()` calls as well.

```r
library(data.table)
lapply(df.list, setDT)

lapply(df.list,
       function(dt) {
         cols <- grep('^lorem', names(dt))
         setnafill(dt, fill = 0L, cols = cols)
         dt[, mean_lorem := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols = cols]
         })
#> [[1]]
#>    foo lorem1968 lorem1969 mean_lorem
#> 1:   1         6         0        3.0
#> 2:   2         0        17        8.5
#> 3:   3         0         0        0.0
#> 4:   4         8        19       13.5
#> 5:   5         0        20       10.0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    ipsum lorem1969 lorem1970 mean_lorem
#> 1:    11         0        22       11.0
#> 2:    12        17         0        8.5
#> 3:    13         0        24       12.0
#> 4:    14        19         0        9.5
#> 5:    15        20         0       10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `rowSums` to save some time on the conversion of NAs to 0:

```
lapply(df.list, function(x) {
    i1 <- grep("^lorem\\d+$", names(x))
    transform(x, avg = rowSums(x[i1], na.rm=TRUE) / ncol(x[i1]))
})
```

timing code:

```
set.seed(0L)
ndf <- 1e4
nr <- 1e4
nc <- 2
df.list <- replicate(ndf,
    data.frame(id=1:nr, matrix(sample(c(1, NA_real_), nr*nc, TRUE), ncol=nc)),
    simplify=FALSE)

mtd0 <- function() {
    lapply(df.list, function(x) {
        i1 <- grep("^X\\d+$", names(x))
        x[i1] <- replace(x[i1], is.na(x[i1]), 0)
        transform(x, avg = rowMeans(x[i1], na.rm = TRUE))
    })
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    lapply(df.list, function(x) {
        i1 <- grep("^X\\d+$", names(x))
        transform(x, avg = rowSums(x[i1], na.rm=TRUE) / ncol(x[i1]))
    })
}

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd2(), check=FALSE)
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result          memory                 time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>          <list>                 <list>   <list>          
1 mtd0()       35.51s   35.51s    0.0282    7.83GB    0.422     1    15     35.51s <list [10,000]> <df[,3] [151,107 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd2()        8.91s    8.91s    0.112     2.98GB    1.12      1    10      8.91s <list [10,000]> <df[,3] [30,314 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Comment: ouh that'll be helpful! Have about 40k observations per df so my laptop is running on capacity anyways xD thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are no NAs in any other columns than those beginning with lorem, you could do the following

```
lapply(df.list, function(df) {
    df[is.na(df)] <- 0
    df$mean <- apply(df[, grep("lorem", names(df))], 1, mean)
    return (df)
})

# [[1]]
#   foo lorem1968 lorem1969 mean
# 1   1         6         0  3.0
# 2   2         0        17  8.5
# 3   3         0         0  0.0
# 4   4         8        19 13.5
# 5   5         0        20 10.0
# 
# [[2]]
#   ipsum lorem1969 lorem1970 mean
# 1    11         0        22 11.0
# 2    12        17         0  8.5
# 3    13         0        24 12.0
# 4    14        19         0  9.5
# 5    15        20         0 10.0
```

Following @akrun answer you can use `rowMeans` instead of `apply(df[, grep("lorem", names(df))], 1, mean)`, i.e.

```
lapply(df.list, function(df) {
    df[is.na(df)] <- 0
    df$mean <- rowMeans(df[, grep("lorem", names(df))])
    return (df)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried yours and akruns answer and finally settled for his since I couln't always guarantee that I have no other NA's. But prefer yours for another case where I don't have any NAs :)

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr`, you can do:

```
map(df.list, ~ select_at(.x, vars(contains("lorem"))) %>%
     mutate_all(~ replace_na(., 0)) %>%
     mutate(avg = rowMeans(.)))

[[1]]
  lorem1968 lorem1969  avg
1         6         0  3.0
2         0        17  8.5
3         0         0  0.0
4         8        19 13.5
5         0        20 10.0

[[2]]
  lorem1969 lorem1970  avg
1         0        22 11.0
2        17         0  8.5
3         0        24 12.0
4        19         0  9.5
5        20         0 10.0
```

If you actually want to keep also the other columns:

```
map(df.list, ~ mutate_at(.x, vars(contains("lorem")), ~ replace_na(., 0)) %>%
     mutate(avg = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("lorem")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
foo <- 1:5
lorem1968 <- c(6, NA, NA, 8, NA)
lorem1969 <- c(NA, 17, NA, 19, 20)
df1 <- data.frame(foo, lorem1968, lorem1969)

ipsum <- 11:15
lorem1970 <- c(22, NA, 24, NA, NA)
df2 <- data.frame(ipsum, lorem1969, lorem1970)

df.list <- list(df1, df2)
#Create function
replace_f <- function(x)
{
  #Replace NA by 0
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  #Compute mean
  #Variable selection
  index <- which(grepl("lorem",names(x)))
  x$Avg <- apply(x[,index],1,mean)
  return(x)
}
df.list2 <- lapply(df.list,replace_f)

df.list2

[[1]]
  foo lorem1968 lorem1969  Avg
1   1         6         0  3.0
2   2         0        17  8.5
3   3         0         0  0.0
4   4         8        19 13.5
5   5         0        20 10.0

[[2]]
  ipsum lorem1969 lorem1970  Avg
1    11         0        22 11.0
2    12        17         0  8.5
3    13         0        24 12.0
4    14        19         0  9.5
5    15        20         0 10.0
```